# Which kind of screw do I need for attaching graphics card connnectors to plates?

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-rec, screws, low-profile

When swithing graphics cards' plates in order to transform them in high profile or low profile graphics cards, sometimes those screws are lost.

How can I get more of them? Which name or reference do I need?

They are almost identical to case-to-motherboard attaching ones, but they have a minimum size difference.

[image]
[image]

Comment: There may be a lead on the ebay store link in this thread (limited access atm, or I would check), looks to be exactly the stand-off/screw/nut you've got pictured - http://www.overclock.net/t/1243730/grafics-card-dvi-port-screw-nut-standoff

Comment: I always scavenge them from obsolete graphics cards.

Comment: If you have an old used computer store in town, they can usually find you some. Additionally, as long as you don't tension your cable, you are usually fine using only one screw (in fact I usually don't screw them in at all on the PC end; just the monitor end, since the weight of the cable will hang from that connection).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz too many graphics cards with no screws, too few old ones xD

Comment: @FrankThomas no old PC stores here, small town...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Which kind of screw do I need for attaching graphics card connnectors to plates?**

### **Hex Nut Screws**

[image] [image] [image]

> How can I get more of them? Which name or reference do I need?

You can do a quick search on the Internet for "**Hex Nut Screws**" but I did a quick search and found two locations to purchase from electronically.

- [Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OM9S3YA) shows a whole kit that's fairly priced
- [Cablewholesale.com](http://Cablewholesale.com) has some fair priced ones as well

  - [Hex Nut Jack Screw, 100 Pieces, # 4 - 40, 11.40mm](http://www.cablewholesale.com/products/serial-modem-cable/cable-assembly/product-30d1-12440.php?utm_source=GoogleShopping&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=30D1-12440&utm_campaign=Hex%20Nut%20Jack%20Screw%2C%20100%20Pieces%2C%20%23%204%20-%2040%2C%2011.40mm&gclid=Cj0KEQjwnv27BRCmuZqMg_Ddmt0BEiQAgeY1lzrjZ85fa8xf68Jpg1nPz78A0IjQzbIy2n4QDcmN2NEaAuJA8P8HAQ)
  - [Hex Nut, # 4 - 40, 100 Pieces, 5.0mm](http://www.cablewholesale.com/products/serial-modem-cable/cable-assembly/product-30d1-02440.php?utm_source=GoogleShopping&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=30D1-02440&utm_campaign=Hex%20Nut%2C%20%23%204%20-%2040%2C%20100%20Pieces%2C%205.0mm&gclid=Cj0KEQjwnv27BRCmuZqMg_Ddmt0BEiQAgeY1lySCzeYoHqNZqaN_n1K7tz2ztSO8f1LGvEonk_lVq_waAk7F8P8HAQ)

You can always call around local computer shops (or search their web sites) or electronic stores in your area and ask them if they sell these.

Comment: Thank you! Tried to find the name on the internet and didn't succeed.